# How can a user Edit a file even when Write bit is off on a file

Tags: files, permissions, vim

Here is the thing i just had a urge to play with umask on my training machine.

i created test user john and logged in using john. and set the umask to 0200 and created a testfile in vim and saved it. Now the permissions for this testfile are

```
-r--rw-rw-. 1 john john 26 Jun 28 12:25 testfile
```

Now i again tried to edit the file and entered some gibberish words.

Now when i try to save using ":wq" editor says file is readonly and can't be saved. But when i added exclamation mark at the end ":wq!" it saved the file.

What just happened ?? even when the write bit is off in testfile

Host OS = RedHat (rhel) 7.2

Answer (score 5):

With "wq", "!" asks Vim to ignore the read-only attribute. From [the documentation](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/editing.html#:wq):

> :wq [++opt]       Write the current file and quit.  Writing fails when
>               the file is read-only or the buffer does not have a
>               name.  Quitting fails when the last file in the
>               argument list has not been edited.
>
> :wq! [++opt]      Write the current file and quit.  Writing fails when
>               the current buffer does not have a name.

Note the difference: without "!", "fails when the file is read-only ..."; that no longer applies with "!".

As to why this happens technically, since you're the owner of the file, Vim can effectively ignore the permissions on it (at worst, [it can change them and restore them](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/src/fileio.c#L4136)). In practice Vim supports a couple of ways to write read-only files:

- if the directory is writable, it will rename the existing file (adding `~` to its name), create a new file, write the new contents to that file, and restore the original file's permissions (this works even if the user running Vim isn't the owner of the file);
- if the directory isn't writable, it will make a backup of the file to a writable directory (`~/tmp` typically), change the file's permissions to make it writable, write the new contents to the file, and restore its original permissions (the only works if the user running Vim is the owner of the file).

Comment: Does the fact that the file is writable by "group" and "others" play in here?

Comment: @Kusalananda , i tested by turning off group's write bit off but still able to edit the file. As Stephen Kitt explained this must be because that john is owner of file so Vim is ignoring the permissions on it.

Comment: It is not because of ownership: try it where your only permission is group or other read. If you can write to the directory then `w!` will work.

Comment: So it's basically unlinking the file and rewriting it?

Comment: @Kusalananda yep

Comment: @richard but it works even if you can't write to the directory, as long as you're the owner. So either works (and Vim handles both). See the linked source code...

Comment: That is correct. I wanted to point out the other mechanism, as people may not be aware and thing it does not matter from a security point of view. However we can see that `vim` can do this across users, if it can write to the directory (and the sticky bit is not set on the directory).

Answer (score 3):

In my answer I will not concern myself with Vim, but instead look at the underlying mechanisms, that you have stumbled upon. It is important to understand these, as it affects the security of your entire system.

It has nothing to do with owner: try it, make a file not owned by you, then give your self read not write. You will get the same results. So why is this?

(though it is possible by being owner, root or having capability CAP_CHOWN, CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE, or CAP_FOWNER, maybe others. )

It is because of the permission of the directory. The directory is writeable, so vim can delete a file and it can add a file. Therefore this is what it does. It removes the old and replaces it with the new.
This makes the w bit on a file mostly advisory (though not if there is no write on the directory).

It probably does it in a safer way than this: move old, create new, delete old.