# Unexpected ability to write to file

Tags: permissions

I have a directory named `dir1`, owned by `root`, with permissions `777`. I have a file named `file1` inside of `dir1`, owned by `root`, with permissions `644`. I'm logged in as a normal user named `user1`.

Why is it that if I edit `file1` inside vim, which states that it is a readonly file, I can save it via `wq!`? My expectation is that unless I `sudo` in, I ought to be denied write access.

I have noticed that following the edit, the ownership of `file1` has changed from `root` to `user1`. I also noticed, if I change `dir1` permission to `775`, my expectations are met. That is, I am denied write access.

Comment: Related: [How can a user Edit a file even when Write bit is off on a file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/292552/how-can-a-user-edit-a-file-even-when-write-bit-is-off-on-a-file)

Comment: Thanks, that clarifies things.

Answer (score 0):

This happened since `dir1` provides write access to all users. A `777` permission allows anyone to poke inside the directory and create/delete contents.

Now, the baseline is, when you use `wq!`, vim deletes `file1` and recreates it using the new permission set, allowing `user1` the write access. This became possible since `user1` has the ability to both delete
and create files inside `dir1`

```
# at beginning    
$ ls -li file1

# after vim wq!
$ ls -li file1
```

But, as soon as you change dir1's permission to `775`, it no longer allows `user1` to create/delete files inside `dir1`. Thus, vim can not delete the original `file1` and recreate it.